# "The lectures are conducted" vs "The lectures are delivered"

Tags: collocations

- The lectures are conducted in English.
- The lectures are delivered in English.

Are above sentences correct and natural? Are there alternative ways to express the same idea?
I intended that the sentences mean "The lectures take place in a way that the professor and students use English to study.".

Comment: As you can see from [this NGram usage chart,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lectures+are+conducted+in+English%2Clectures+are+delivered+in+English&year_start=1940&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=10) both verbs are about equally common. Use whichever you like best - there's no scope for your choice to make any difference to the *meaning*. I'm afraid your *The lectures take place in a way that the professor and students use English to study* is invalid and probably meaningless. All the main two assertions mean is the lecturer (and any students raising queries) spoke in English.

Answer (score 1):

- The lectures are in English.
- The lectures are given in English.
- The lectures are taught in English.

I think "conducted" one is also fine.

Comment: I don't understand why you would endorse *given* but not *delivered*, which has the same meaning.

Comment: That can also be OK.